# Distinct vs Identical blocks when partitioning a set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the examples below:

$1$: In how many ways can a city council of $30$ be divided into $5$ committees, with each member serving on exactly one committee? In addition, how many ways if each committee must consist of exactly $6$ members?

Answer: $5^{30}$ and $\displaystyle{\binom{30}{6, 6, 6, 6, 6}}$, respectively.

$2$: How many ways are there to arrange $20$ different books into three piles?

Answer: $S(20, 3)$ where $S(n, k)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind

In the first example the committees must be distinct. I assume that's because each one contains a different person. But then in the second one the piles are supposed to be identical even though a book cannot be in three places at once. What makes the committees above distinct and the piles identical?

Comment: Almost nothing except perhaps history and convention.  The problems should have explicitly included instruction as to whether to treat the committees / piles as distinct or indistinct.  As an aside, I disagree with an answer of $5^{30}$ for the first part of the first problem as that allows for some committees to be empty, but again, that is a valid interpretation to the problem and isn't incorrect per se.

Comment: When talking about committees, it is sometimes assumed that each committee will be working on a different problem/task and can thus be differentiated based on what problem/task they are working to solve.  But, I will reiterate, this is merely convention that some people follow but not necessarily all people follow.  A well written problem will leave no ambiguity as to the intended interpretation.  Thankfully, in the real world when coming up with and asking questions like this, you get to decide yourself if you treat them as distinct/indistinct based on your personal preference.

Comment: @JMoravitz, cool. Here's a link to a problem similar to the first one where the distinctness of blocks is signaled by indexing them: https://ibb.co/CHLLxsL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that because these are word problems, they are subject to a little bit of interpretation, but I will explain the commonly accepted interpretations.

Bob and Janet form the Committee for Energy, Jason and Rick form the Committee for Education, and Ryan and Dave form the Committee for Budget. All of these committees have names, and therefore make them distinct. If Bob and Janet moved to the Committee for Budget, while Ryan and Dave move to the Committee for Energy, this would be considered a new arrangement.

I have Encyclopedia Britannica's volumes 1,3,5 on one pile, and 2,4 on another pile. After they've been checked out, I put them back as 2,4 in one pile, and 1,3,5 in another pile. The piles here are essentially the same, because they consist of the same books. It is arguable that they are different piles because they are placed in different locations, but from a mathematical ideal, you are now adding extra criteria to the problem, as there is no mention of location, only the piles themselves.